# how to parse json object inside json object in java in the Guardian API?

Tags: android, json

I want to parse JSON data from API the Guardian news to Java Android for my app. The JSON data is JsonObject inside JsonObject. I have to try several ways, but still not return the data.

> JSON data

```
{
   "response":{
      "status":"ok",
      "userTier":"developer",
      "total":1,
      "content":{
         "id":"us-news/2019/sep/09/us-briefing-taliban-talks-brexit-turmoil-and-nadal-wins-us-open",
         "type":"article",
         "sectionId":"us-news",
         "sectionName":"US news",
         "webPublicationDate":"2019-09-09T10:25:05Z",
         "webTitle":"US briefing: Taliban talks, Brexit turmoil and Nadal wins US Open",
         "webUrl":"https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/sep/09/us-briefing-taliban-talks-brexit-turmoil-and-nadal-wins-us-open",
         "apiUrl":"https://content.guardianapis.com/us-news/2019/sep/09/us-briefing-taliban-talks-brexit-turmoil-and-nadal-wins-us-open",
         "fields":{
            "headline":"US briefing: Taliban talks, Brexit turmoil and Nadal wins US Open",
            "standfirst":"<p>Monday’s top story: Taliban warn of further US deaths after Trump says he cancelled peace talks. Plus, why the breakup of Big Tech is beginning at last</p>",
            "trailText":"Monday’s top story: Taliban warn of further US deaths after Trump says he cancelled peace talks. Plus, why the breakup of Big Tech is beginning at last",
            "byline":"Tim Walker",
            "main":"<figure class=\"element element-image\" data-media-id=\"9c05cc7c0e69a78aa3f71f94a4bdd28e3d044a48\"> <img src=\"https://media.guim.co.uk/9c05cc7c0e69a78aa3f71f94a4bdd28e3d044a48/0_124_5610_3364/1000.jpg\" alt=\"Afghans at the site of a deadly car bomb attack in Kabul last week.\" width=\"1000\" height=\"600\" class=\"gu-image\" /> <figcaption> <span class=\"element-image__caption\">Afghans at the site of a deadly car bomb attack in Kabul last week.</span> <span class=\"element-image__credit\">Photograph: Rahmatullah Alizadah/Xinhua/Barcroft Media</span> </figcaption> </figure>",
            "body":"<p><em><a href=\"https://www.theguardian.com/info/2018/sep/17/guardian-us-morning-briefing-sign-up-to-stay-informed\">Subscribe now</a> to receive the morning briefing by email.</em></p> <p>Good morning, I’m Tim Walker with today’s essential stories.</p> <h2>Republicans and Democrats denounce Taliban talks</h2> <p>Lawmakers from both sides of the aisle have criticised Donald Trump after <a href=\"https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/sep/08/donald-trump-says-he-was-due-to-host-taliban-at-camp-david\">he revealed </a><a href=\"https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/sep/08/donald-trump-says-he-was-due-to-host-taliban-at-camp-david\">he had planned a secret peace summit</a> with the Taliban at Camp David on Sunday, <a href=\"https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/sep/08/donald-trump-cancelled-taliban-talks-camp-david-typical-hot-cold\">only to call it off at the last minute</a>. ",
            "wordcount":"1172",
            "commentCloseDate":"2019-09-12T10:30:00Z",
            "commentable":"false",
            "firstPublicationDate":"2019-09-09T10:25:05Z",
            "isInappropriateForSponsorship":"false",
            "isPremoderated":"false",
            "lastModified":"2019-09-09T10:48:23Z",
            "productionOffice":"UK",
            "publication":"theguardian.com",
            "shortUrl":"https://gu.com/p/ca9ye",
            "shouldHideAdverts":"false",
            "showInRelatedContent":"true",
            "thumbnail":"https://media.guim.co.uk/9c05cc7c0e69a78aa3f71f94a4bdd28e3d044a48/0_124_5610_3364/500.jpg",
            "legallySensitive":"false",
            "lang":"en",
            "bodyText":"Subscribe now to receive the morning briefing by email. Good morning, I’m Tim Walker with today’s essential stories.",
            "charCount":"7006",
            "shouldHideReaderRevenue":"false",
            "showAffiliateLinks":"false",
            "bylineHtml":"<a href=\"profile/walker-tim\">Tim Walker</a>"
         },
         "isHosted":false,
         "pillarId":"pillar/news",
         "pillarName":"News"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to loop the content data, and get `webTitle`, `fields`, also `body` inside `fields`.

Thanks, advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this

```
// Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);

        //Create the JSONObject with the key "response"
        JSONObject responseJSONObject = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");

        // Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "content",
        // which represents a list of news stories.
        JSONObject newsContentArray = responseJSONObject.getJSONObject("content");

        Iterator<String> keys = newsContentArray.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (newsContentArray.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                Object webTitle = newsContentArray.get("webTitle");
                Object webPublicationDate = newsContentArray.get("webPublicationDate");

                JSONObject fields = newsContentArray.getJSONObject("fields");
                String body = fields.getString("body");
                String main = fields.getString("main");

                setTextNews(webTitle.toString(), webPublicationDate.toString(), main, body);
            }
        }
```